# Run Time error while integrating Pusher Android Titanium Module

Tags: android, titanium, runtime-error, titanium-modules

I have been trying to integrate Pusher Android module in my app. After much struggle i was able to compile the module and package it with my application. But now when I try to require the added module in my application I am getting RunTime error.
I have limited experience with Android. Can some suggest what wrong am I doing here.?
Environment:

- Application type: mobile
- Titanium SDK: 3.3.0.GA
- Platform & version: Android 16,
- Device: Android emulator
- Host Operating System: Windows 7
- Titanium Studio: 3.3.0.201407100905
- Logs:

  ```
  [ERROR] :  TiApplication: (KrollRuntimeThread) [1375,1375] Sending event: exception on thread: KrollRuntimeThread msg:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:    37 cannot locate '__cxa_end_cleanup'...
  [ERROR] :  TiApplication: ; Titanium 3.3.0,2014/07/11 12:36,787cd39
  [ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:    37 cannot locate '__cxa_end_cleanup'...
  [ERROR] :  TiApplication:
  [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
  [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
  [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.loadExternalModules(V8Runtime.java:114)
  [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.initRuntime(V8Runtime.java:81)
  [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.doInit(KrollRuntime.java:175)
  [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:109)
  [ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: KrollRuntimeThread
  [ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:    37 cannot locate '__cxa_end_cleanup'...
  [ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:
  [ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
  [ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
  [ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.loadExternalModules(V8Runtime.java:114)
  [ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.initRuntime(V8Runtime.java:81)
  [ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.doInit(KrollRuntime.java:175)
  [ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:109)
  ```

Comment: are you facing same issue with 3.2.3 GA ?

Comment: I tried with both 3.2.3.GA and with 3.3.0.GA.

Answer (score 1):

You should check NDK Path and add the compiler option "-lsupc++" due to your code may be using C++ exception mechanism and call __cxa_end_cleanup somewhere. lsupc++ (libsupc++.a)

Also, you should add -fno-rtti to avoid other maybe-encountered compilation error, this is because all android's C++ class is compiled without dynamic type info in class memory layout.

I hope my answer helps you ;)

Comment: Can you please let me know how to add these compiler options in Titanium.

Comment: [Titanium Documentation says](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide): "You can also include an optional jni folder. This optional folder (as of Titanium SDK 2.1.0) can include C or C++ code to compile shared libraries. You are required to have an Application.mk file in this directory if it is present. Modules using JNI or NDK support via shared libraries will work with both the V8 and Rhino runtimes."

Comment: So Do I have to create a separate JNI folder as <module>/android/jni and inside jni folder create a Application.mk file. And what C or C++ code do I will have to write. I am sorry I have very limited experience in Android development.

Comment: I have the same problem here : http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/177251/. The thing is that creating any module creates the libio.xxx.so files in the module. We don't have to compile anything with NDK